# How do I refresh a Chrome website opened with Qt - QProcess

Tags: qt, google-chrome, qprocess

Starting an instance of the Chrome Browser via Qt / QProcess works fine.
(Windows OS)

```
QString program = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "http://www.google.com";
QProcess *chromeProcess = new QProcess(this);
chromeProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

But how do I trigger a refresh of the opened page?
I don't want to open a new tab.

Comment: I doubt you can, web browsers generally don't allow external programs to control them to that level.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with QProcess, consider using tools such as xdotool for Linux.

Comment: Windows is unfortunately required. Is there a way to send a key stroke like Ctrl+R?

Comment: @LiquiNUX Try smth. like https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5213874a-603e-4378-835d-f6488f382d47/how-do-i-input-to-another-application?forum=csharpgeneral .

Comment: Oh, great idea, thanks. I'll give it a try. The good old Windows dll's.